# php - get a link's value

Tags: php, html

I'm using php to get a part of a html file:

HTML file:

```
<div class="titles">
    <h2><a href="#">First Title</a></h2>
</div>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    $url = 'http://example.com';
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $titles = $html->find('.titles');
    $heading = $titles->find('h2')[0];
    $link = $heading->find('a')[0];
    echo $link; 
    //result: <a href="#">First Title</a>
?>
```

How can I separately get the value of href and 'a' tag?

Because I want to save the title and link into the database,

I need '#' and 'First Title' not the 'a' tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$link` should be a Simple HTML Element *object*, of which you can access attributes using `$link->href` and the text contents as `$link->plaintext`. See http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm.

Answer (score 0):

U can use DOMDocument and DOMXpath object's (>=php5)

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

part of sample code:

```
$html = '<div class="titles">
<h2><a href="#">First Title</a></h2>
</div>';


$page = new DOMDocument();
$page->loadHtml($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($page);
$a = $xpath->query("//a");

for ($i=0; $i < $a->length; $i++) {
    $_a = $a->item($i);

    echo  $_a->getAttribute("href");
    echo "<br>";
    echo  $_a->textContent;


}
```